# ElementAPI: How to order and/or limit results?

Tags: plugin-elementapi, order, limit

Currently collaborating on a site with another developer, which is using ElementAPI pretty heavily for content delivery.

Is there a way to limit the number of returns on any given json feed? Say; only return the 10 most recent entries in any given channel? Or order the returned data by a specified field asc/desc?

A sample code:

```
'trucks.json' => [
  'elementType' => 'Entry',
  'criteria' => ['section' => 'trucks'],
  'paginate' => false,
  'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {
    return [
      (int)$entry->id,
      $entry->manufacturer,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
'criteria' => [
    'section' => 'trucks',
    'limit'   => 10,
    'order'   => 'title asc',
]
```

The [Element Criteria Model documentation](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel) has more information about setting criteria.

#### Update for Craft 3.x*

```
The “order” element query param has been deprecated. Use “orderBy” instead.
```

* Craft v3.0.11 reports this in the `/admin` under `deprecation errors`

Comment: Ah that did the trick. I tried that but not from WITHIN criteria, only after criteria.

Comment: Is there a means to change the sort via the api, versus doing it on the front-end?

Comment: Updated my answer with an "order" parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Just setting the limit property doesn’t do the trick alone, you need to deactivate pagination, too:

```
'criteria' => [
    'section' => 'trucks',
    'limit'   => 10,
    'orderBy'   => 'title asc',
],
'paginate' => false,
```